# Web request issue [ok from Postman but not from python]

Tags: networking, request, icmp

When I try to send web requests (any kind) from Postman, it goes through the network and I can see the response. If I want to do the same from Python (I use spyder IDE), I get a http connection error.

Basically, the requests are timed out.

When I do a tracert to any host (i.e. google.com), after a number of hops the requests are getting timed out.

I'm on company network. We use dynamic proxy file to direct requests.

My question is twofold:

1. What is the root cause of the issue?
2. How can I fix it on my end? (Not involving company IT.)

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this issue with the help of company IT. Problem was - if anyone interested - that I wrongly defined the proxy in the request itself, so that it never reached the proxy. Once I changed the proxy settings, the request could go through.